# How to run Popen with arguments without "-e" in gnome 3.36.9

Tags: python, argparse, popen

I had topic here before but my problem is not solved...

I used an older version of Gnome for a very long time and my script worked very well. I have installed the latest version Gnome (3.36.9) and there is a small problem that does not interfere with the use of the program. I'm talking about an error:

```
Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal. # Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
```

It doesn't stop me from using or running the program, but I wanted to get rid of the bugs in the console.

My older, working initial code looks like this:

```
    # <--- CONFIG ---> #
    os.chdir("/home/administrator/program/cartypes")
    car1 = "audi"
    color1 = "black"
    engine = "diesel"
    # <--- CONFIG ---> #
    
    p1 = Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--wait', '-e','python3 ./program.py --car ' + car1 + ' --color ' + color1 + ' --engine ' + engine1])
    time.sleep(5)
    p1.communicate()
    p1.wait()
    print("End!")
```

I read a bit and changed "-e" to "--" that is:

```
p1 = Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--wait', '--','python3', './program.py'])
```

And theoretically the program starts, but unfortunately it doesn't work anymore when I add argparse to the code and I don't know how to connect working script with arguments send to program.py as that was before in first code with "-e":

```
p1 = Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--wait', '--','python3', './program.py'])
```

with:

```
./program.py --car ' + car1 + ' --color ' + color1 + ' --engine ' + engine1
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of the concatenation and make them separate list elements.

```
p1 = Popen(['gnome-terminal', '--wait', '--', 'python3', './program.py', '--car', car1, '--color', color1, '--engine', engine1])
```

Your original code also didn't quote or escape the variables, so you could run into problems if any of them contain quote characters.